# amdgpu-pro fails to install on 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, amd-graphics, additional-drivers

I upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 today (yeah I'm late :-/) and tried to install the amdgpu-pro driver. But after I downloaded and extracted the files, when I run `amdgpu-pro-install` I get the following error(s):

```
$amdgpu-pro-driver/amdgpu-pro-install
[sudo] password for MYUSER: 
deb file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro/ ./
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Release
Ign:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Release
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Ign:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Get:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Ign:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Get:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Ign:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Ign:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Get:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Ign:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Get:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Ign:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Ign:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Get:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Ign:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Get:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Ign:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages [6.987 B]
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Ign:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Get:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Ign:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Get:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Ign:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Ign:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Get:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Ign:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Get:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Ign:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Ign:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en_US
Get:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Ign:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-en
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
Get:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Ign:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Translation-de
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
Err:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Packages
  File not found - /var/opt/amdgpu-pro/./Packages (2: No such file or directory)
Hit:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/opt/amdgpu-pro/./InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
W: The repository 'file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro/./Packages  File not found - /var/opt/amdgpu-pro/./Packages (2: No such file or directory)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro-lib32
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro-dkms
```

I would guess that AMD just screwed up the local repo, but I'm not too familiar with that.

Thank you for any help!

Some system info (I don't think it matters here):

Graphics: Radeon R9380X

Kernel: 4.4.0-38

Comment: You need to run it with sudo.

Comment: But the first thing it does is asking me for my sudo password..
(sorry, that was not in the qoute because I had typed it before, I added it now)

EDIT: tried it with explicit sudo in front - same result

Comment: I'm having the same problem and @CelticWarrior is *not* correct. Any luck resolving this?

Comment: Edited the `amdgpu-pro-driver/amdgpu-pro-install` script on line 47 to `                PACKAGES="amdgpu-pro-lib32 amdgpu-pro-dkms"` and on line 81 to  `echo "deb [trusted=yes] file:$REPOSITORY/ ./" | $SUDO tee $(source_list)`.  However, even after adding `amdgpu` to `/etc/modules`, I have yet to see my GPUs in `dmesg` or `lspci` :'[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree and had the same error with Ubuntu 16.10 and amdgpu version 16.50-362463.

I needed to change the last line of function source_list() (at line 69) from

```
echo ${dir}${etc}${sourceparts}/amdgpu-pro.list
```

to

```
echo ${dir}${etc}/${sourceparts}/amdgpu-pro.list
```

to overcome these errors.

Comment: Could you please clarify which file you edited?

Comment: @Zanna i'm 99% sure he edited the `amdgpu-install` script

Answer (score 1):

You might try running the installer NOT as root.

So don't  sudo -i  or anything.

Don't  sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install   either.

Just run as unpriviliged user who can use the  sudo  command.  The script will call sudo for you, but if you are already root it won't be able to "drop" privileges later.   Buggy because it assumes a umask when it should define one specifically.

Comment: sudo adduser --force-badname --system --home /nonexistent --no-create-home --quiet _apt

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/1543280

Comment: Or you may have to modify the script by adding sudo chown -R _apt /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local

Near the $REPOSITORY mkdir line

Comment: Could also be a bug where the amdgpu-pro-install is assuming a umask setting of 000 when you might have a more secure 077